# 'Can be' or 'could be'

Tags: tense, conditionals

I was talking to a friend about a family event I had attended the preceding night, and I wanted to say something to this effect: "I forgot just how much fun family gatherings could be if they were spaced out well." But the tense seems flawed to me for some reason. Could you please explain the flaws in the following sentences?

I forgot just how much fun family gatherings could be if they were spaced out well

I forgot just how much fun family gatherings could be if they **are** spaced out well

I forgot just how much fun family gatherings **can be** if they **are** spaced out well

Comment: You can use either _can_ or _could_  - the present tense because it still applies, or the past tense because you had the thought yesterday. However, the tenses must agree, so the middle sentence doesn't work.

Comment: This could be answered using a dictionary  - just look up "can" and "could".

Comment: @Astralbee OP will come across many different definitions of "can" and "could" without knowing which one applies because dictionaries don't tell you that. The bar for that close vote is "entirely answerable using a dictionary". This is not that.

Comment: @gotube There is still an expectation that the author of the question tried to find an answer before posting. If a dictionary definition can't answer this question, it would be helpful for the author to explain why that didn't help.

Comment: @ColleenV All of the close votes are for not using a dictionary. That won't help Ahmed improve the question

Comment: @gotube If people are mistakenly thinking the question can be answered with a dictionary, the best way to prevent further close votes is to edit the question to explain what the author already knows about the difference between "could" and "can", and why knowing the meaning from the dictionary doesn't help.